# What Windows SDK for monitoring user activities?

Tags: windows

Most of our staffs required to work from home, and I want to build a system similar to https://app.activtrak.com/

I know this kind of system required Win SDK,

Can anybody point me the right Win SDK documentation that can give me information?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getactivewindow

or this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getforegroundwindow

If you need to do some Googling, the term you likely want to use is "active window." I was not going to create an account on the website just to answer this question, but I assume it is activity tracking software of some sort.